# Parsing events using CLNDR.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Currently, I am using a vendor supplied piece of javascript that renders a tinycal and when the user clicks on a date, I am given a list of events from an external source (looks to be RSS).

However, I'd like to make my own since this one is clunky and is throwing synchronous xml requests - and so, I am starting with using CLNDR.js. Though, my question is can I get it to function like my current calendar? If so, how might I go about doing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated (as is suggestions of other plugins if they meet the criteria).

CLNDR.js: https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR
Current: http://kb.evanced.info/article.php?id=331

Comment: Why did you tag MooTools in this question?

Comment: I may also be trying to use a mootools version of a calendar to achieve my desired effect